# An (extended) semimetric on surfaces

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Given a smooth surface $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$, like the surface of sphere, we can define the following extended semimetric $d : S^2 \to [0, \infty]$, where
$$
d(x,y) = \inf\{\lVert x - p\rVert + \lVert p - y\rVert : p \in \mathbb{R}^3 \cup \{\mathbf{\infty}\}, \text{lines } \overline{xp} \text{ and } \overline{py} \text{ are tangent to } S\}.
$$

Has this construction been studied in the literature? This might have generalizations into higher diimensions, manifolds with tangent spaces and so on.